# How to update model after making json get request? (Angular JS)

Tags: ajax, json, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a simple page that shows set of records according to year.
Just a note, the sidebar is not highlighting selection properly.

[image]

I am able to load the data the first time i come to this page. But when i try to change year and hit go, the main content area goes blank and the url changes to localhost:8080/cg/

Here is my controller code.

```
        app.controller('AnnualReportController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

            $scope.annuals = [];
            $scope.selection = 0; // gives me the year value from the drop down.

            // initial load that works
            $http.get('annualReport/list').success(function (data) {
                $scope.annuals = data;
                $scope.selection = data.year;
            });


            // on-click event for 'Go'  
            $scope.searchGo = function () {
                $http.get('annualReport/list', {params: {year:$scope.selection}
                }).success(function (data) {
                    $scope.annuals = data;
                    $scope.selection = data.year;
                });
            }
        }]);
```

Can someone please tell mew how i can update the model and view my data?

Here is my partial for this controller..

```
        <h1 class="page-header">Annual Report - {{annuals.year}}</h1>

        <div>
            <select ng-model="selection" ng-options="o for o in annuals.yearList"></select>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="searchGo()">Go</a>
        </div>

        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Property Name</th>
                    <th>Submitted</th>
                    <th>Year</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="annual in annuals.properties | orderBy : 'name'">
                    <td>{{annual.propCgName}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-change="checkUpdate(annual)" ng-model="annual.submitted">
                    </td>
                    <td>{{ annual.year }}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

I think i found the culprit. its the href="#" in my 'Go' button, thanks to Grumble Snatch's comment!

If i change to href="" it seems to work. Which brings another question, that is whether it is okay to have blank href in html?

Thanks everyone who contributed their time to help me out!  :)

Comment: Can we please see how you've written your "go" button in html?  My idea based on your description is that the button is doing more than we think (routing away from the desired view somehow)

Comment: could you share your html code tooo

Comment: try this: **angular.copy(data, $scope.annuals);**

Comment: Is your "go" button part of a `form` or does it have the type `submit`? You want to make sure that isn't the case.

Comment: I suspect what Grumble Snatch thinks is right.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to tell you without seeing the whole code. Still what I can see from here is you need to change your code in proper way like below,

Let's say in your .html page outer div is there within which other html tags are taken. so first put ng-init directive to outer div,

.html(Let's call it dashboard.html)

```
<html>
....
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" // your angular module name
         ng-controller="AnnualReportController" // your angular controller 
         ng-init="initDashboard()">

      ..................// other html controls..............
     </div> 

</body>
</html>
```

AnnualReportController.js

```
app.controller('AnnualReportController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
               // I have removed first two declaration.....

             $scope.initDashboard=function()
             {
                  // put this code with in this initDashoard function :)

                 // initial load that works
                $http.get('annualReport/list').success(function (data) {
                $scope.annuals = data;
                $scope.selection = data.year; // here I don't think you need to define $scope.selection=0 because above line data.year must be assigning some value to $scope.selection.

                 });
             }

            // on-click event for 'Go'  
            $scope.searchGo = function () {
                $http.get('annualReport/list', {params: {year:$scope.selection}
                }).success(function (data) {
                    $scope.annuals = data;
                    $scope.selection = data.year;
                });
            }
        }]);
```

This will surely work. If doesn't let me know and come up with your html code.... :)

Comment: Hi micronyks, thanks for taking time to answer my question. I found how you wrapped everything inside initDashboard interesting as an alternative way of doing the same.